# WPF ContextMenu: How can I tell who launched it?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ContextMenu that can be opened from 2 different StackPanel's, how can I tell which panel actually launched the menu?

Under WinForms I could consult the SourceControl of the ContextMenuStrip to find this information.

TIA,
Martin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, what you're looking for is the [`PlacementTarget`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placementtarget.aspx)-property of the ContextMenu.